# mysqli selecting data from table returning error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to this but managed to track my issue down to this error:

> Error description: Unknown column 'huhuhu' in 'where clause'0

Query:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE description = ".$postcode_q." LIMIT 1");
```

It seems it's looking for a column from the `$postcode_q` but that is what I'm trying to search for. It's a table called "cscart_postcode_location_descriptions" and wanting to search the column "description" within that table with the value that's passed to `$postcode_q`.

Any ideas what's wrong there?

### Update

```
<?php

//if we got something through $_POST
if (isset($_POST['postcode_locator_search'])) {
    // here you would normally include some database connection
    //include('config.local.php');

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','test','c@W)ukmd[0bm','test');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    // never trust what user wrote! We must ALWAYS sanitize user input
    $postcode_q = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postcode_locator_search']);
    //$postcode_q = htmlentities($postcode_q);

    // A select query. $result will be a `mysqli_result` object if successful
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE description = '".$postcode_q."' LIMIT 1");
    echo("Error description: " . $postcode_q);

    if($result === false or mysqli_error($mysqli) === 0) {
        // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: No huhuhu is the query im passing to search the column description

Comment: Is your connection connects in the database?

Comment: yes it does not sure whats happening

Comment: try to make sql like this : `code` $sql = sprintf('SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE description = '%s' LIMIT 1',$postcode_q);`code`

Comment: @MaximLaktionov: it would be better to use parameter binding here. That saves the need to add quotes, makes `mysqli_real_escape_string` redundant, and would be generally considered as safer in security terms.

Comment: However, yes, it looks like the error here was merely invalid SQL - strings need to be enclosed in quotes.